# Loops and Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, loops, get

It appears to me that there could be a better way to this, maybe using loops, I think.

```
 String hora1 = listaH.get(0);
 String hora2 = listaH.get(1);
 String hora3 = listaH.get(2);
 String hora4 = listaH.get(3);
 String hora5 = listaH.get(4);
 String hora6 = listaH.get(5);
 String hora7 = listaH.get(6);
 String hora8 = listaH.get(7);
 String hora9 = listaH.get(8);
```

Is there another way to write this using less words? 
Thanks

Comment: If you need a seperate variable to hold each element, why maintain an array to begin with?

Comment: If you're willing to do operations on each element per occurrence (that is, you don't use a variable for each), then **yes**.

Comment: If you need nine separate variables, then the answer is "no". If you would be fine with an `String[] hora` array of nine elements, then yes.

Comment: Each string shows me a different word. But I want all the strings to do the same thing: ".setText()" in a jLabel. I have 9 jLabels created and I want one string per label.

Comment: Why not create the JLabels, set their text, and add them to your panel/frame in a loop that iterates over your listaH? Or maintain a separate list/array of your labels that coincide with the strings you want them to display.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you want to achieve and what you hope to gain from it...but...

Assuming that `listaH` is `java.util.List`, you could use

```
for (String horse : listaH) {
    System.out.println(horse);
}
```

(NB: You can do the same thing with arrays)

Take a look at [The `for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [The `while` and `do-while` statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

```
  Iterator itr = listaH.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext()) {
     String element = (String) itr.next();
     System.out.print(element + " ");
  }   

 or 

 for (int i=0;i<listaH.size();i++) {
        String element  = (String)listaH.get(i); 
        System.out.print(element + " ");
  }
```

if you need String array then use this one

```
String[] array = listaH.toArray(new String[listaH.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Instead of separate variables for each element, you should just leave them in the original list and then access them that way.  So, for example, when you need the value that you are trying to store in `hora9`, use `listaH.get(8)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays for hora variable. It can be like

```
String[] hora = new String[9];
```

Now you can use any loops, but for is best for your case.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 9 ; i++){
 hora[i] = listaH.get(i);
}
```

But why waste resource and complexity on new variables? You can do something like `listaH.get(4)` wherever you need hora5.